# Why aren't complex compact Lie groups trivial?

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups

What's wrong with my understanding of Liouville's theorem?

A complex lie group is one where group multiplication and inversion are holomorphic. Supposing $G$ is compact and complex, so is $G \times G$. Then multiplication could be viewed as a holomorphic function on a compact set, so it must be constant valued in $G$ by Liouville's. Then since, in particular, the identity times itself is the identity, so is any element times any other element. But this only makes sense if $G=\{e\}$.

I've seen that there is no hesitation in saying that the adjoint representation $\textrm{Ad}: G\to \textrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ is holomorphic on a compact set and so constant by Liouville in the same context. I assume that the difference must be in that the functions "multiplication" and "inversion" take values in $G$ instead of some other space, but I don't understand what we lose.

Comment: How do you view a map $G\times G\to G$ as a function to ${\mathbb C}$?

Comment: I thought Liouville was only for single-variable functions?  No?

Comment: This only applies to holomorphic functions into $\mathbb C$.

Comment: As for the adjoint, the target is a vector space, so one can apply the L.T. to components of that map. The bottom line: read the statement (and the proof!) of the L.T.

Comment: The identity function on a compact complex manifold is holomorphic and not constant. As others have said, Liouville is for maps to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Right, I was imagining you compose the multiplication with charts on G to make it a holomorphic map into some $\mathbb{C}^n$, and then you should be able to apply Liouville to the components here. What's wrong with this?

Comment: The problem is that no single chart will work for all of G.  Forget about groups for a moment, and just consider any nonconstant map $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (here $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the compactified complex plane, a sphere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liouville's theorem applies to holomorphic functions from a complex manifold to $\mathbb{C}$: specifically, it says any holomorphic function from a compact complex manifold to $\mathbb{C}$ is locally constant.   More generally, it follows that the same conclusion holds for holomorphic functions to $\mathbb{C}^n$, or holomorphic functions to a complex manifold that embeds in $\mathbb{C}^n$.  So it applies to $\textrm{Ad}: G\to \textrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ since picking a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$, $\textrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ is just $GL_n(\mathbb{C})\subset\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$.

However, Liouville's doesn't typically apply to holomorphic functions $G\to G$, since $G$ typically does not embed in $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Indeed, if $G$ did embed in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then Liouville's theorem would apply to the embedding itself and would show that $G$ must be discrete (this works for any compact complex manifold, not just Lie groups).

[Note that even if Liouville's theorem applied, it would only tell you that your map is *locally* constant, so $G$ is discrete, not necessarily trivial.]

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a bit miffed by circle group $U(1)$. I feel like this is a complex group which embeds in $\mathbb{C}$, it is compact and connected, and yet it is of course not trivial or discrete. Why doesn't the sort of argument that makes $\textrm{Ad}$ constant apply here? Something to do with that multiplication and inversion on the circle extend to unbounded entire functions on all $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $U(1)$ is not a complex Lie group!  It is not a complex manifold at all.  An $n$-dimensional complex manifold has charts that make it look locally like $\mathbb{C}^n$.  But $U(1)$ looks locally like $\mathbb{R}$, not like $\mathbb{C}^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: oooooops ya thanks! I guess this means, incidentally, that the complex torus doesn't have embeddings into affine space? Neat...

Comment: That's correct.  In the case of a 1-dimensional complex torus, this is just the very classical fact that any nonconstant elliptic function must have poles (so it does not give a map from a torus to $\mathbb{C}$).